# azure premium storage page blob/30 cost

Tags: azure, azure-storage

recently we had deployed one application in Azure. For that we choose Virtual Machine(Standard DS2 v2 (2 cores, 7 GB memory)), and SQL Server Standard.But when I look into Billing, I found that premium storage page blob/30 burns higher than Computer Pricing. How can I cut price on this.:

[image: img]

Comment: hi srinu dasari how to change premium disks to standard storage are you manged it?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Pricing for Azure Disks Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/disks/) mentioned that Premium Disks would be charged basing on the three disk sizes: P10, P20, P30. Based on the Premium Disk size your chose, you would be charged at $135.17 per month. If you leverage Premium Storage snapshots to backup data, then there is an additional billing at $0.132/GB per month.

For more details about your billing, you could log in to [account.windowsazure.com](https://account.windowsazure.com/Home/Index), click Download Usage Details to download the spreadsheet for your billing. You could follow [tutorial](https://www.petri.com/understand-your-microsoft-azure-spending) and [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-understand-your-bill/) to understand your Azure Costing. If you couldn't get any helpful info, please try to [contact support](https://portal.azure.com/?#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade) for locating your issue to reduce your cost.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for reply.Actually I want to change Premium Disks to Standard Storage.I went through portal.azure, but I could not find any option to change. And I have raised a service request to support.Still waiting for reply from Support team